# Quotes in PHP array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with PHP code in my job, and some of it is pretty bad.  As I was working on a file, I saw this:

```
$array["$rowID"]['value'] = $value
```

Is there any reason that `$rowID` should be wrapped in double quotes?

The following obviously works fine:

```
$array[$rowID]['value'] = $value
```

Is that just personal preference, or is there a reason why the key is double quoted?

Comment: Thanks guys.  I figured there was no reason to double quote the variable.  I was trying to figure out why the previous developer did that.  I hate other people's code =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no extra functionality gained by that. It probably slows it down because it is trying to see if there is any literal content in the string as well as any variables to evaluate.

Comment: Well, since all numeric indexes are forced to `int`, it does slow it down (since it needs to do two type conversions instead of 0: `int->string->int`)...

Answer (score 2):

Go for the second version. There is no difference in end-result, but the second is faster. The first has to interpolated by PHP, whereas the second can be tokenized without any extra effort.  (The difference in the two however, is trivial.)

Since the second version is easier to read, go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Two words: **Variable interpolation**.

In PHP, double-quoted strings are special because they are parsed for any variables in the string, and it will output the literal value of the variable if it finds any.

So in this case the end result is exactly the same.

I'd suggest using the second method because it saves the extra time it would take to parse the string.

Answer (score 1):

nope. not only no reason, you might want to cast $rowID if validation is not being done properly in other places. such as `$array[(int)$rowID]['value']`

Comment: `$rowID` is coming from a database call, so it's the right type.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to do it the way shown is to force whatever that variable is to be a string. Say, for example, $rowID were an object and that object has a toString() method. In case one, it'll be keyed to that string. In case two, it would crash.

Comment: I didn't say it was the only way to do it. Just that it was the only reason TO do it.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks.  That would make sense.  `$rowID` is an int, so it doesn't matter.  Sometimes I really hate other people's code...

Comment: Actually.. I'm not 100% sure, but this code may even be setting the key to the string '1' and not 1. Thus using the hash table in associative arrays and slowing the code down EVEN MORE. I can't remember off hand if PHP auto-converts strings that are ints into ints or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of tricky situation, as $array["$rowId"] will address an array map value based on a STRING key, while $array[$rowId] would address the array map based on the type of scalar value that $rowId is.  Unless $rowId is a string, I could see this potentially causing issues.

Try this out and see if it makes any difference

```
$index = 5;
$intIndexArray = array($index => "hello");
$stringIndexArray = array("$index" => "world");
echo $intIndexArray["$index"];
echo $stringIndexArray[$index];
```

if any difference exists, neither "hello" or "world" will be printed...

Comment: I actually just tested this, and it makes no difference.  Thanks!